# Get URLs opened in all tabs using Chrome.tabs api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to check in how many tabs my application is currently opened using chrome.tabs api whenever **onbeforeunload event** occurs in application.

So I wanted to know if it is possible to do it using chrome.tabs if yes then how can it be done.

Comment: There is a similar question asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109296/is-there-any-way-to-count-number-of-tabs-are-opened-in-chrome Check this and if it didnt help, ask for more help.

Comment: Are you trying to capture some state before a window closes or when chrome closes? Since chrome exit won't guarantee events callbacks firing before closing.

Comment: onbeforeunload is for synchronous code only so none of chrome.* API with callbacks would work there because the callbacks are invoked asynchronously. You'll have to maintain a list of URLs constantly in a [global] variable, for example by using chrome.tabs.onUpdated and onRemoved events.

Comment: @holmberd basically my Idea was to clear asp.net websites session as soon as it gets closed from all the tabs of chrome. SO by using Chrome.tabs I will find in how many tabs application is opened and if it is 0 then clear the session by callback.

Comment: @SagarShirke but is this for when a specific window closes, or chrome itself?

Comment: @holmberd.. it is for both, Chrome close and Tab close

Comment: @SagarShirke ok, then as I mentioned in the beginning, chrome doesn't guarantee that your callbacks will have time to fire when chrome is closing. Once chrome start to close, then some of your events, `chrome.windows.onRemoved` or windows unload, might be called; but since there is no guarantee your "clean-up" will take place, it might leave your extension in a non-consistent state.

Answer (score 1):

```
chrome.tabs.query({windowType:'normal'}, function(tabs) {
    console.log('Number of open tabs in all normal browser windows:',tabs.length);
});
```